# Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, pipewire, bluetooth-le

### The problem

When I try to connect to my bluetooth headset with `bluetoothctl`, sometimes it fails with:

> Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Rebooting the `bluetooth` service does not help. Rebooting the whole computer seems to help: it seems like every second boot is fine. As if there was a race at boot time and I need to be "lucky" for the right module to be loaded correctly.

I have seen many suggestions online to set `ControllerMode = bredr` in `/etc/bluetooth.main.conf`, but it doesn't help.

I see something suspicious in `dmesg`, but I don't know what to do about it (and it is there even when bluetooth works, so it's probably unrelated):

> Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.

### More details

I am running on Alpine Linux with Wayland and Pipewire. The sound works with the laptop speaker, it really seems related to bluetooth. Also when it works, I don't get the error above ("br-connection-profile-unavailable") and instead `bluetoothctl` says that it connected successfully.

I installed `bluez` following the [instructions here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Basic_Installation):

```shell
# apk add bluez
# apk add bluez-deprecated
# modprobe btusb
# adduser $USER lp
# rc-service bluetooth start
# rc-update add bluetooth default
```

The `btusb` module is loaded:

```shell
% lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  81920  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btmtk                  12288  1 btusb
btintel                57344  1 btusb
bluetooth            1081344  25 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbcore               413696  6 xhci_hcd,usbhid,usb_storage,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it works when the `bluetooth` service is started *before* I start Sway, but it does not work if the `bluetooth` service is started *after* Sway (in which case it results in "org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable").

Maybe that is because `pipewire-launcher` is started by Sway, and it has to be started after `bluetooth`? Not sure.